# RoutingError (No route matches [GET]) on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, acts-as-votable

In my app i am using act_as_votable to vote my products, it works fine on localhost but on heroku am getting:

```
RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/products/1/like"):
```

**My routes**

```
resources :products do
    member do
      put "like" =>"products#upvote"
    end
    resources :previews, except: [:show, :index]
  end
```

**Products Controller**

```
def upvote
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to @product
  end
```

in my product show page

```
<%= link_to like_product_path(@product), method: :put do %>
          Add to Wishlist
          <% end %>
```

i thought it was happening because of jquery so i have added jquery in the show page but the issue remained the same. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use a [`button_to`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to) instead, it will produce a `POST` request by default.

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Wishlist', like_product_path(@product), method: :put %>
```